# JavaScript - How do I place a DOM element into a variable the variable in later functions?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, dom, parseint

I am trying to turn `rectangle.style.width = "100px";` into a variable using parseInt so that I can place that variable into two buttons so I can either increase the width of my rectangle or decrease it. However I cant seem to get the information into the variable no matter what I do.

My two functions are very similar with the only diffrence being that one subtracts and the other adds.

```
//does not work as supposed to
function shrinkBtn() {
myWidth= myWidth - 10 + "px";

//works but does not have the element as a variable

function shrinkBtn() {
rectangle.style.width = parseInt(rectangle.style.width)- 10+ "px";
}
```

I would have thought that this would have been super simple but I havent had any luck with any of answers I have found from previous posts or google searches.

I have tried a couple diffrent things when facing this issue. I have tried

```
var myWidth = rectangle.style.width;
var myWidth = parseInt(rectangle.style.width);
```

I do get a output when I place it in a console log such as console.log(myWidth) however it doesnt seem to work when I try to put it in my other functions. I was expecting to be able to store the information into the variable and then place it in my function such as

```
function  shrinkBtn() {

  myWidth = parseInt(myWidth) -10 + "px"; 
}
```

or

```
function  shrinkBtn() {

  myWidth = myWidth - 10 + "px"; 
}
```

EDIT: added full code

```
rectangle.style.width = "100px";
// rectangle.style.width = parseInt(rectangle.style.width)+ 10+ "px";
var myWidth = parseInt(rectangle.style.width);
console.log(myWidth);

decreaseBtn.addEventListener("click", shrinkBtn);

increaseBtn.addEventListener("click", growBtn);

function  shrinkBtn() {
//using the variable here does not trigger the function
  myWidth = parseInt(myWidth) -10 + "px"; 
    
//using this style below does trigger the function
  // rectangle.style.width = parseInt(rectangle.style.width)- 10+ "px";
    
}


function growBtn() {
    //Original function without the variable to show comparison This works 
    rectangle.style.width = parseInt(rectangle.style.width)+ 10+ "px";
}
```

Comment: What is the initial value of the `myWidth` variable and where was it declared? What is the initial variable of the `rectangle.style.width` property and where/how was the element created?

Comment: there is no initial value of the '''myWidth''' variable, I was trying to set it directly to the DOM element which has a value of 100px (or 100 when I use the parseInt function) as for where it is declared, I have it on line four as a global variable. after my "rectangle.style.width"     The '''rectangle.style.width''' was created in my index.html file as ''' <div id="rectangle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>'''   I am calling the DOM element form my HTML file to my javascript.

Comment: btw ... [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) is [to be used with the 2nd `radix` parameter for good reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#description).

Comment: @PeterSeliger Ive done it both ways, the 2nd radix and without, it didn't make a diffrences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP might have a look into a function's [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method.

Thus as for the next provided example one does not register handler functions which each do query the specific element each time the handler gets invoked, but one does create and register two handler functions where the element is bound as the created function's `this` context (the OP should think in terms of two methods which do operate each on the bound object).

```js
function decreaseWidthOfBoundElement() {
  this.style.width = parseInt(this.style.width, 10) - 10 + "px";
}
function increaseWidthOfBoundElement() {
  this.style.width = parseInt(this.style.width, 10) + 10 + "px";
}

function main() {
  const elmNode = document.querySelector('#rectangle');

  document
    .querySelector('#shrink')
    .addEventListener(
      'click', decreaseWidthOfBoundElement.bind(elmNode)
    );
  document
    .querySelector('#increase')
    .addEventListener(
      'click', increaseWidthOfBoundElement.bind(elmNode)
    );
}

main();
```

```html
<div id="rectangle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>

<button id="shrink">-</button>
<button id="increase">+</button>
```

In addition one can bind arguments too which provides even more options for the customization of changing an element's size (e.g. implementation of just a single function which then gets used for binding).

```js
function changeSizeOfBoundElement(deltaX = 0, deltaY = 0) {
  this.style.width = parseInt(this.style.width, 10) + deltaX + "px";
  this.style.height = parseInt(this.style.height, 10) + deltaY + "px";
}
function enableElementChange(changeRoot) {
  const changeNode = changeRoot
    .querySelector('[data-element]');

  const decreaseNode = changeRoot
    .querySelector('[data-decrease-values]');
  const increaseNode = changeRoot
    .querySelector('[data-increase-values]');

  const decValues = decreaseNode.dataset.decreaseValues
    .split(',').map(value => Number(value.trim()));
  const incValues = increaseNode.dataset.increaseValues
    .split(',').map(value => Number(value.trim()));

  decreaseNode
    .addEventListener(
      'click', changeSizeOfBoundElement
        .bind(changeNode, ...decValues)
    );
  increaseNode
    .addEventListener(
      'click', changeSizeOfBoundElement
        .bind(changeNode, ...incValues)
    );
}
document
  .querySelectorAll('[data-element-change]')
  .forEach(enableElementChange);
```

```css
[data-element-change] { margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

```html
<div data-element-change>
  <div data-element style="width: 70px; height: 70px; background-color: orange;"></div>

  <!-- data-decrease-values="<deltaX>,<deltaY>" -->
  <button data-decrease-values="-10">-</button>
  <button data-increase-values="10">+</button>
</div>

<div data-element-change>
  <div data-element style="width: 200px; height: 50px; background-color: purple;"></div>

  <!-- data-decrease-values="<deltaX>,<deltaY>" -->
  <button data-decrease-values="-20,-5">-</button>
  <button data-increase-values="20,5">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a simpler method to this? I am only trying to extract the rectangle.style.width into a variable so I can just use that in my functions. Im not trying to do all these other things. I just want to be able to use the variable for my functions instead of directly changing it by using rectangle.style.width.  I want to parseInt() the rectangle.style.width. and use it in a variable. nothing more. A lot of this seems extremely unnecessary for what I am trying to do.

Comment: O.k. back to start then ... _"`myWidth= myWidth - 10 + "px";`"_ ... `myWidth` of cause can be made accessible via a function too. But what does the OP want to do with `myWidth` in addition to in/decreasing it? And what does _"`... //does not work as supposed to`"_ or _"`... //works but does not have the element as a variable`"_ actually mean?

Comment: And regarding the OP's question ... _"How do I place a DOM element into a variable the variable in later functions?"_ ... the first `bind` example of the above provided answer already implements the most straightforward and simple approach.

Answer (score 0):

we don't have a full snippet so not so easy to answer!

Local variable problem (local, global, rewrite)? Like in your function myWidth= myWidth - 10 + "px";... myWidth???

Element not selected???

You were not far by the way...

```js
document.querySelector('#shrink').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const rectangle = document.querySelector('#rectangle');
  rectangle.style.width = parseInt(rectangle.style.width) - 10 + "px";
})

document.querySelector('#increase').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const rectangle = document.querySelector('#rectangle');
  rectangle.style.width = parseInt(rectangle.style.width) + 10 + "px";
})
```

```html
<div id="rectangle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>
<button id="shrink">-</button>
<button id="increase">+</button>
```

I've put 2 functions for better understanding. It could be simplified.

Comment: I have edited the initial question to include the full code.